# Change mouse cursor on table, but not on th

Tags: html, css

I search a way to change the mouse cursor on row but not on one of the title (th)

I created an example

http://jsfiddle.net/9xckcuze/

```
table{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: try to use `table td{
    cursor: pointer;
}`

Answer (score 7):

Add css for `th` tag:

```
table{
    cursor: pointer;
}
table th{
  cursor:default;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table{
  cursor: pointer;
}


th  {
  cursor: hand;
}
```